# Create NSMutableDictionary that will be available from everywhere in the app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to have a `NSMutableDictionary` that will pull it's data from the web, and will be available from any view controller in the app.

In other words, I should be able to get and set the info in that `dictionary` in any part of the app.

I've read several solutions to this, one being to create an .h file that will contain that dictionary, and then add that .h file to the .pch so it will be available anywhere.

And the second option was to create the dict in `AppDelegate`, however people said it's a bad solution.

Please advise on the best way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: UIMutableDictionary or NSMutableDictionary...

Comment: Man, that's embarrassing. I guess, I've been working too much :)

Comment: haha...keep it up man:)

Comment: I think your second option is better. It works..

Comment: @Kalpesh no that is a bad idea. You should keep app logic out of the app delegate. The best solution is to create a singleton that you can access from anywhere. See Anil's answer below. That is what you need to do.

Comment: @Fogmeister Ok bro . I will definetly do it in my application . Thanks for clearing my bad idea..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use singleton class for sharing the data
Check this [Singleton class](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/)

`MyManger.h`

```
#import <foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyManager : NSObject {
NSMutableDictionary *_dict
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *dict;

 + (id)sharedManager;  
@end
```

`MyManger.m`

```
#import "MyManager.h"

static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;

 @implementation MyManager

 @synthesize dict = _dict;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods  

+ (id)sharedManager {
 @synchronized(self) {
    if(sharedMyManager == nil)
      sharedMyManager = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
 }
return sharedMyManager;
} 

- (id)init {
   if (self = [super init]) {
  dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   }
 return self;
}
```

You can access your dictionary from everywhere like this

```
   [MyManager sharedManager].dict
```

Comment: This sounds interesting, but since I'm still a newbie, it sounds too complicated for now. Is there a more in depth tutorial for this, that you could recommend?

Comment: [This will help you](http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/iOS-5-How-To-Share-Data-Between-View-Controllers-using-a-Singleton)

Comment: @Anil Thanks for the example and code. I accept your answer for now, and will try to use it in my app. But I'm sure I'll be back with questions :)

Comment: @SergeyCatraniuc  Welcome..:) [Check this](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/) for the detail implementation

Answer (score -1):

you can create it in the app delegate and set its setters and getters. and each time you need to acces it you can make and instance of the main delegate

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```